# JS/jquery get variable text based on id of clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to understand how to get a set variable string based on the clicked elements id (the variable and id are the same).

```
var testingid = "testing";
var testingid2 = "testing2";

$('[id ^=inst][id $=STD]').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var text = this.id; //how do I turn the ID to get the set variable?

    console.log(text);

});
```

So if I click element with id testingid, the console will output "testing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of separate variables, combine the values to an object, with keys by the names of the `id` values. To get the value, pass the id to the object.

**Note**: you can use a Map instead of an object.

```js
var ids = {
  testingid: "testing",
  testingid2: "testing2"
};

$('button').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var text = ids[this.id];

  console.log(text);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="testingid">testing</button>

<button id="testingid2">testing2</button>
```